# Bluemix DevOps Editor Text Direction

Tags: google-chrome, editor, ibm-cloud, devops

I use Bluemix DevOps editor with chrome.
When opening a file for editing, text shows Right-to-Left direction.
How can I switch it to be Left-to-Right ?
I tried chrome addon "switch direction" with no success.
Problem does not appear with Firefox.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your chrome language set to a RTL locale?

The editor settings page has a Globalization category where you should be able to disable BIDI support.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Explaining what BIDI stands for might help the nonexperts who come along, and your question to Orit might be better served as a comment than an answer.